# How to get a list of all routes used in a Hanami app?

Tags: routes, hanami

We have a way to get all the routes used in Rails and Sinatra as below

Rails: `Rails.application.routes.routes`

Sinatra: `Sinatra::Application.routes`

Similarly, How can we get all the routes used in Hanami app?

Comment: Have you tried [`Hanami.routes`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/hanami/Hanami/ApplicationConfiguration#routes-instance_method)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

#routes(blk) ⇒ Object

#routes(path) ⇒ Object

#routes ⇒ Hanami::Config::Routes

Specify a set of routes for the application, by passing a block, or a relative path where to find the file that describes them.